# jquery get index of hovered li

Tags: jquery, indexing, html-lists

All I want to do is return the index of the i that is hovered over, the ul has a class .around

This looks like it should work

```
$('.around li').on("mouseover", function(event){
var myindex =  $('.around').index(this);
console.log(myindex);
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
$('.around li').on("mouseover", function(event){
var myindex =  $(this).index();
console.log(myindex);
})
```

Comment: attention: wrong usage of index results in much less performance: http://jsperf.com/coll-index-elem-vs-elem-index

Answer (score 1):

maybe you're trying to do this:

```
var li = $('.around li');
li.on("mouseover", function(){
   var myindex = li.index(this);
   console.log(myindex);
})
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MKExb/

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is bad when it comes to performance. Much better to cache query, and use delegates, so that only one handler will be set on ul, and then every event will be delegated to the li on which the mouse is. I modified the original jsfiddle, have a alook, works like a charm, and the code is not even longuer:

http://jsfiddle.net/zhkjLoet/1/

```
var ul = $('.around'); // cache query
ul.on("mouseover","li", function(event){ //delegate events to li child
   var myindex = $(this).index();
   console.log(myindex);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like this:

```
var listItem = document.getElementById('bar');
alert('Index: ' + $('li').index(listItem));
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.around li').each(function () {
                $(this).bind('mouseover', null, function () {
                    var index = $('.around li').index(this);
                    console.log(index);
                });

            }, function () { });

        });

</script>
```

or much cleaner one

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.around li').hover(function () {
            var index = $('.around li').index(this);
            console.log(index);
        }, function () { });

    }); 
    </script>
```